# SAP HANA Stored Procedure Table doesn't exists

Tags: stored-procedures, hana

I have two stored procedures, the first one (SP1) creates a table, and the second one (SP2) uses that table.

I cannot run both SP sequentially in one statement.

```
CALL SP1();
CALL SP2();
```

I get an error saying " Could not find table/view..."

when SP2 was created, the table existed due to testing SP1, but now I got rid of all the tables that are created temporarily during runtime SP2 doesn't run.

I realize I can just run SP1 and then SP2 and that will work, but there are 39 SPs and they take about 2 hours when running one after another, so waiting would make the process take even longer.
The only solution I can think of is to just leave the tables that are needed and truncate them rather than drop them. If nothing else can be done I will have to do that, but I rather drop them. The person that created this SPs was evil enough to create over 500 of these tables so I don't want them permanently in my schema.

As a side note, these tables are used for debugging mainly so they can be dropped after a few days of execution, once the processes validated.

I wonder if there is any way to ignore the error or something like or any other workaround.

Thanks in advance for your time and expertise.

Regards,
Leonardo

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to run it regardless of the missing tables.

I just had to put each SP in a different DO BEGIN.... END; block, that seems to be only validating one block at a time and since the previous block creates the table that use going to be used on block number 2, everything seems to be working fine.

```
DO
BEGIN
    CALL SP1();
END;

DO
BEGIN
    CALL SP2();
END;
```

and so on.

The blocks have a bit more things in them, I just put the SP call to simplify them.

I am just leaving this here in case someone else has the same problem as I have.

I would still appreciate it if someone has a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like that those tables are in fact *temporary* tables used to "transfer" data between the different stored procedures.

With HANA it is not necessary nor recommended to dynamically create tables for that use.

Instead, use table variables and "hand over" the data via table typed parameters.

That way, no tables have to be created/dropped at runtime at all.

Also, since table variables are effectively handled as internal, session local temporary tables, a lot of overhead is removed (i.e. those tables don't need to take care of logging or concurrent access) which makes them a lot more lightweight and better performing than dynamically created tables.

Another negative aspect of dynamically creating objects is that this always comes with locking of the database catalog, checking for and invalidating potentially dependent objects, and numerous internal caches.

If possible, one really should avoid this if performance is important.

Comment: I just saw your comment. :( The tables are regular tables, not temporary nor dynamically created. It's just the fact that SP2 doesn't know about the tables that will be created in SP1. When you create a table within an SP it knows that, although it might not exists right now, it will when the SP runs so any part of the SP that uses a nonexisting table, know that it will be created. However, it seems like SPs don't share scope even if "father" SP calls both "child" SP. Anyway, I just learned to live a life with the workaround I found. Thanks for your time. :)